# Railsapps template crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps, rails-composer

I am using the following config.
`RVM
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.18`

And trying to create a new app using the command:

```
rails new . -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

with the following choices:

question  Install an example application for Rails 3.2?
4)  rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan

question  Web server for development?
3)  Unicorn

question  Web server for production?
1)  Same as development

question  Template engine?
1)  ERB

question  Continuous testing?
1)  None

extras  Set a robots.txt file to ban spiders? (y/n) n
extras  Create a GitHub repository? (y/n) n
extras  Add 'therubyracer' JavaScript runtime (for Linux users without node.js)? (y/n) n

And in the middle of the template execution i get the following:

```
models
 models  recipe running after 'bundle install'
 gsub    config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
The template [https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb] could not be loaded. Error: No such file or directory - /home/qas/Dropbox/code/telco/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
```

Please assist on how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have a file `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`?

Comment: As the error suggests the file is not present. And I am not sure if I can create the file beforehand as the template is doing all the work of creating and modifying the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent release of [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) failed to support Rails 3.2 and Devise. It is fixed now. Try:

```
rails new . -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer-Rails3_2.rb
```

Support for Rails 3.2 will be dropped from future versions of Rails Composer. If you can, use Rails 4.1, and the [rails-devise-pundit](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit) starter app.

Comment: Should have thanked you earlier and am sorry for being late. Thanks for the quick response. This helped.